# Tensorflow: TypeError: helper must be a Helper, received: <class 'helper.GreedyEmbeddingHelper'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

Hello I am trying to create a BasicDecoder with a GreedyEmbeddingHelper but it is giving an error:

```
TypeError: helper must be a Helper, received: <class 'helper.GreedyEmbeddingHelper'>
```

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
        elif self.mode == 'decode':

            # Start_tokens: [batch_size,] `int32` vector
            start_tokens = tf.ones([self.batch_size, self.dimension], tf.float32) * 0.1337
            end_token = 0.1337

            def project_inputs(inputs):
                print inputs.shape
                return input_layer(inputs)

            if not self.use_beamsearch_decode:
                # Helper to feed inputs for greedy decoding: uses the argmax of the output
                decoding_helper = helper.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(start_tokens=start_tokens,
                                                                end_token=end_token,
                                                                embedding=project_inputs)
                # Basic decoder performs greedy decoding at each time step
                print("building greedy decoder..")
                inference_decoder = seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=self.decoder_cell,
                                                         helper=decoding_helper,
                                                         initial_state=self.decoder_initial_state,
                                                         output_layer=output_layer)
            else:
                # Beamsearch is used to approximately find the most likely translation
                print("building beamsearch decoder..")
                inference_decoder = beam_search_decoder.BeamSearchDecoder(cell=self.decoder_cell,
                                                           embedding=project_inputs,
                                                           start_tokens=start_tokens,
                                                           end_token=end_token,
                                                           initial_state=self.decoder_initial_state,
                                                           beam_width=self.beam_width,
                                                           output_layer=output_layer,)
```

I don't know how to fix it because Helper is an abstract class. So it won't be possible.

Comment: How have you imported the GreedyEmbeddingHelper? helper.GreedyEmbeddingHelper?? Maybe this path can help: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/GreedyEmbeddingHelper

Answer (score 0):

GreedyEmbeddingHelper is defined at tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper.
So instead of `helper.GreedyEmbeddingHelper`, use `tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper`